# How to reload / refresh data from server in Ng-Repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

How do I refresh the data in NG-repeat

Here is the setup

**Controller :**

```
     angular.module('pApp').controller('KController', ['$scope', 'getInfo', 'addInfo', function ($scope, getInfo, addInfo)
{

    $scope.add = function (a, b, c) {
                var items = [];
                items.push(a, b, c);
            addInfo.addP(items).success(function () {
          $scope.updatedprocess();
            });
                });     
    }
    $scope.updatedprocess = function () {
        getInfo.getP().success(function (data) {
            $scope.pInfo = data.d.results;
        })
    };


    $scope.updatedprocess();

    }]);
```

**Service**

```
angular.module('pApp').service('getInfo', function ($window, $http) {

    var requestDigest = $window.document.getElementById("__REQUESTDIGEST").value;



    JSRequest.EnsureSetup();
    var hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(JSRequest.QueryString["SPHostUrl"]);
    var appweburl = decodeURIComponent(JSRequest.QueryString["SPAppWebUrl"]);


    this.getP = function () {
    var requestUrl = appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle('Processes')/items?@target='" + hostweburl + "'";
           return $http({
        url: requestUrl,
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        }
    });
};
```

**HTML (View )**

```
    <input  class="productDDL" ng-model="query" type="text" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" placeholder="{{selectedProduct}}" >

<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2" > 
     <li  ng-repeat="product in pInfo| filter: query | orderBy: 'name'  track by product.Id"><a href="" ng-click="selectProduct(product.Title)">{{product.Title}}</a></li>
  </ul>
```

am using modal to add the info to the List

```
<div class="modal-footer"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="close()">Close</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="add(locationname,ddlproductTypes,ddlBusinessUnits)">Add</button>
</div>
```

the submit button is calling the $scope.add() function in the controller .

The value in the $scope is updating

But in view Ng-repeat is not updating without page refresh

Please help me how to update dynamically

Thanks

Comment: When should it refresh? It won't happen magically. You need a button or something that calls your updatedprocess() function to reload the data from server.

Comment: Hello 

I am adding new item though the modal and I have added updateprocess () in the function of item added